# Remote server with pre-installed software and GUI

Tags: vps

I'm teaching Django & MySQL course and the question is: Is there any service which allows to connect to the remote server with pre-installed software.

Here is functionality I want:
1/ Have remote server with Linux/Windows and GUI
2/ Install there software I want (e.g., Django, python, mysql) or have it pre-installed
3/ Enable multiple logins and users : I don't want my students to install the software on their desktops, but to connect to the server and practice there.
Each student should have his own session and working space.
It's kinda VPS(Virtual Private Servers), I guess. But VPS is rather expensive way.

Answer (score 0):

buy a server with WHM + cPanel + Softaculous.
If a VPS is expensive, try to found a WHM reseller package with Softaculous.
With WHM you can create hosting accounts for your students each one with a cPanel access.
With Softaculous your students can install software on the server in 1 click.
Regards.